# python : save dictionary into list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, scrapy

I have a code like this:

```
item = CitytalkItem()    #scrapy item 
event = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("...")
for d in event:
    event_date = d.find_element_by_xpath("td[1]")
    event_time_type = d.find_element_by_xpath("td[2]")
    event_locate = d.find_element_by_xpath("td[3]")

    event_date_c = event_date.text
    event_time_type_c   = event_time_type.text
    event_locate_c  = event_locate.text
    #save like  {"event_date": "0808", "event_tim_type": AM "event_locate": "LA"}
```

and I want to save it to a list
The form like this:

```
 item['event']: 
           [{"event_date": "0808", "event_tim_type": AM "event_locate": "LA"},          
           {"event_date": "0708", "event_tim_type": PM "event_locate": "BA"},   
           {"event_date": "0810", "event_tim_type": AM "event_locate": "LA"},   ]
```

Please teach me
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
events = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("...")
item['event'] = [{'event_date': event.find_element_by_xpath("td[1]").text,
                  'event_time_type': event.find_element_by_xpath("td[2]").text,
                  'event_locate': event.find_element_by_xpath("td[3]").text} 
                 for event in events]
```